# How to identify whether a client is sending file to server using C# in VS2010?

Tags: c#, sockets

I am having a server client program using C# in VS2010, in which client is sending a file to server and server responds the client with another file. What I want is to keep my server going for that I am using function

```
IPAddress[] ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses("MRD044");
for (int i = 0; i < ipAddress.Length; i++)
{
    if (ipAddress[i].AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
        ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress[i], 5656);
        sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
        sock.Bind(ipEnd);
     }
 }
 curMsg = "Starting...";
 Console.WriteLine(curMsg);
 sock.Listen(10);
 curMsg = "Running and waiting to receive file.";
```

Now I want to run the getFile() function which performs the receiving function of server side, to run only when a client is sending the file to the server. like :

```
if(clientSendingFile())
{
    getFile();
}
else
{}
```

Comment: How does your code run on the server? Within IIS? Or as a standalone-exe? Anyway, google for "client server c#" and you'll be set.

Comment: you might want to clarify what your question is there but it seems you are looking for a tutorial on the subject of writing a client server program that receives files from the server. Heres one such:

`[web]:`http://socketprogramming.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/send-file-from-server-to-client-using-c.html

Comment: No no! nothing like that MR. john Faulkner rest I am done with it.Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your call to `sock.Listen(10)`, call the Accept method to wait for an incoming connection:

```
Socket clientsocket = sock.Accept();
```

Then your implementation of clientsocket may look something like this:

```
// pseudo-code - I might have a missed a C# thing or two...
void getFile()
{

  byte [] buffer = new byte[1000];


  while (true)
  {
      int count = -1;
      try
      {
          count = clientsock.Receive(buffer);
          // write count bytes into the file - however you are doing that
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
           // error
           count = -1;
           break;
      }
  }
```